# How can I avoid "not in ecosystem" errors thrown by comma IDE?

Tags: raku, commaide

I have a test file in my module's `t/` directory that does a `use` on a `TestUtils` files which has some variables and routines:

```
use Test;
use TestUtils;

plan 4;
check_cmd_output('No arguments');
check_cmd_output('Successfully ingested', test_md_file);
check_cmd_output('Successfully ingested', test_md_file, 1);
check_cmd_output('Successfully ingested', vimwiki_arg_sim());
```

It works fine. However, Comma was complaining about `TestUtils` not being found "in the ecosystem" as well as throwing errors with identifiers from the `TestUtils` module that it was not loading:

[image]

I was able to stop Comma from complaining by:

1. Exporting the identifiers in the `TestUtils` file
2. Fully qualifying the identifiers in my test file with something like: `TestUtils::check_cmd_output(...)`
3. Adding `TestUtils` to the `provides` hash in the META6.json file.

I'm thinking there is probably a better way. I tried doing stuff like `use lib 't'` and `use lib '.'` but that did not help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comma doesn't handle this situation perfectly; it understands (following the IntelliJ platform naming conventions):

- Source roots, which are used as roots for resolving `use` statements within the project (anything not resolved is assumed to be from the module ecosystem)
- Test roots, where test files are found (used for, for example, being able to run tests in an `xt` directory)

These are, however, mutually exclusive. If the `TestUtils` module were to be placed in a `lib` directory inside of `t`, then that `lib` directory could be marked as a source root, and the symbols should be resolved.

Comment: I thought about putting in `lib` but decided against that that because it would break convention. So there's no way to tell Comma/IntelliJ to make `t` a "source root?"

Comment: You can mark it as a source root, but I believe it then ceases to be a test root. So far as breaking convention goes, I've tended to put test support modules under a `t/lib`, but I've seen them go directly into `t` also, so I'm not sure there is a solid convention here.

Comment: Ah, I missed the "inside of t" bit in your OP. Thanks! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to get it working. I added a t/lib directory and added TestUtils into it. Then I right clicked the `t/lib` directory in the "projects" pane, and marked it as a sources root (I tried both as a "test" root and plain "sources" root) and restarted IDE. I'm still getting red squiggles from Comma. Tests still run and work fine.

Comment: I should specify that I'm not getting red squiggle on the `use TestUtils` line any more but I am getting it on the other identifiers. All identifiers in TestUtils are exported and global. Tests still run fine with no errors so they are getting found at run time.